# Nodejs Wit.ai - breaking up custom actions into seperate modules

Tags: node.js, wit.ai

im looking for some help in taking the actions object (ex):

```
const actions = {
    say(sessionId, context, message, cb) {
        console.log(message);
        cb();
    },
    merge(sessionId, context, entities, message, cb) {
        cb(context);
    },

    GetLocation(sessionId, context, cb) {
        console.log("location = san luis obispo");
        cb(context);
    },

    error(sessionId, context, err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    },
};
```

and break them up into separate module files. my custom actions will be quite involved and i don't want to create a messy file... im not a nodejs pro, so any help would be awesome!

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create another js file export it, and import where you want, an example, there ara a lot of ways to do the same.

customActions.js

```
'use strict';

const GetLocation = (sessionId, context, cb) => {
    console.log("location = san luis obispo");
    cb(context);
};

const API = {
    GetLocation,
};

module.exports = API;
```

and import in your file

```
const customActions = require('./customActions.js'),

const actions = {
    say(sessionId, context, message, cb) {
        console.log(message);
        cb();
    },

    merge(sessionId, context, entities, message, cb) {
        cb(context);
    },


    GetLocation: customActions.GetLocation

    error(sessionId, context, err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    },
};
```